# CodeLens wrong/incomplete after moving file in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, codelens

We just moved one solution in TFS to another folder and now all the CodeLens are only showing one change (the move) and only "the mover" as the only person having changed the method (even if he did not actually touch the method).
In the "Source Control" => History the move is the only "top level item" and all previous changes I am not seeing in the CodeLens are nested underneath the move.

**Can this be changed, so I see the "correct/complete" CodeLens again?**

Answer (score 2):

This is *at least* partially addressed in upcoming VS2013 Update 2, which is out in preview form.  Once you moved/renamed the solution, you introduced a "branch" operation in TFS, and the original indicator only showed the current info, not working back through any branch info.

In VS2013 update 2, we added more support to handle branch operations and hopefully show more information than you have now.  I thought there was a blog post about the branch info, but the only one I can find is a related post about the new incoming changes indicator:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/03/03/new-codelens-indicator-incoming-changes.aspx

(my team used to be responsible for the changes,etc indicators, but we aren't any more, so i'm not sure *exactly* if your issue is *entirely* fixed there or not.)

Edit: note that the indicator only shows data it gets from the server, so in order to see incoming changes or branch information in any of the TFS powered indicators, you also need the corresponding update to the TFS server that drives this info.

Comment: Installed the CTP on my VS, but did not change anything for my case. Is the CTP also required on the TFS (which I can not install there)?

Comment: yeah, you wont see branch info in indicators in the CTP unless the corresponding server side changes have been made to your TFS server too.